# how to get method from another file undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my query mysql file i try to include my FileDataRead module to read and get the params for etablish the connection.

I don't see what I've missed :(

**The error:**

> logger': undefined method `read_config_file' for Logging:Module (NoMethodError)

**My loging module file:**

```
module Logging
  include FileDataRead

  def logger
    Logging.logger
  end

  def self.logger
    @conf = read_config_file('logging')
    @logger ||= Logger.new(@conf['name'])
    @logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
                              "[#{datetime.strftime('%F %T')}] #{msg}\n"
                             }
    @logger
  end
end
```

**The reading file:**

```
require 'yaml'

module FileDataRead
  #include logger

  def read_config_file(var)
    config = YAML::load_file(File.join('config.yml'))
    if var == 'database'
    # logger.info("database".colorize("cyan", :style =>"strikethrough"))
      puts "database"
      @conf = config['database']
    elsif var == 'logging'
      puts "logging"
      @conf = config['logging']
    elsif var == "mail"
      @conf = config['mail']
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include a module, ruby adds the modules methods as instance methods. I believe what you want to do is have the methods in FileDataRead added to the Logger module as class methods. Ruby allows you to do this using the keyword `extend`.

```
module Logger
  extend FileDataReader

  # rest of the code stays the same

end
```

Doing this will make `read_config_file` a class method in Logger, meaning it can be called from within another class method. A lot more information can on this can be found [here](http://blog.metova.com/ruby-modules-include-vs-extend/).